# How about making the categories of CSE.SE and ME.SE the same?

Tags: support, footer, site-categories

I noticed that on https://stackexchange.com/sites, the site [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) is categorised under "Professional", while [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) is categorised under "Science".

Why are these two different? Their categories should be the same, for example, "Science".

Answer (score 9):

If there were to be a rearrangement of categories, perhaps an Education category would be appropriately added to the mix.

Comment: This is really the correct answer if such a thing could ever be created.

Answer (score 4):

It certainly does not make a ton of sense for the two to be in separate categories.  However, if you consider a hypothetical third site, "English Teachers", then it seems fairly clear that Professional would make more sense for sites focused at *educators*, who are, after all, coming to the SE network to grow within their profession.

Comment: Note: There is a proposal of [*Science Educators*](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113414/science-educators?referrer=5t-fm35J97Cdzv01y6-b-g2) at Area 51

Comment: CSEducators doesn't seem to be very similar to the other sites classified as "Professional". But ComputerScience and Mathematics aren't really Science either (with a few small subcategories of each excepted).

Comment: @nekketsuuu Nevertheless, by categorizing under science, what you are saying is that Educators' sites would not share a primary affiliation with each other.  That makes little sense to me (and would also nullify this particular meta question)